# How to add google registry (gcr.io) as 3rd party registry (docker cloud)?

Tags: google-container-registry, docker-cloud

I followed this [Google container - using an access token](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_an_access_token) but it does not work.

The error is:
Cannot authenticate with gcr.io: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: eu.gcr.io/v1/repositories/organization/repository/tags

However, it works on my machine using docker login and docker pull.

It looks like the token is fine because if I put one wrong it returns this error:

Cannot authenticate with gcr.io: 403 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: eu.gcr.io/v1/repositories/organization/repository/images

Could anyone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloaded the JSON private key file. Then run:

```
docker login -u _json_key -p "$(cat keyfile.json)" https://gcr.io
```

This will allow you to run normal docker commands